# If $f$ is symmetric linear operator then $(Ker\,f)^\top\leq Im(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f:\ \mathbb R^n\longrightarrow\mathbb R^n$ be a linear map. Moreover, $f$ is symmetric, which means
$$f(x)\cdot y=x\cdot f(y),\ \forall x,y\in\mathbb R^n.$$
I want to show that

(a) $Ker\,f^\top\leq Im(f)$

(b) $Ker(f^2)\leq Ker(f)$

Could anyone give me some hints for this problem ? Thank you